# how to make a query constrained by a collection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the following collection stored in a session:

```
  "trienios" => array:4 [▼
    0 => {#276 ▼
      +"curso": "TGEI"
      +"trienio": "2014-2017"
    }
    1 => {#277 ▼
      +"curso": "TGEI"
      +"trienio": "2015-2018"
    }
    2 => {#278 ▼
      +"curso": "TGEI"
      +"trienio": "2016-2019"
    }
    3 => {#279 ▼
      +"curso": "TGEI"
      +"trienio": "2013-2016"
    }
  ]
```

And I want to make a query constrained by the values present on the collection. This is the query I actually have:

```
$alunos = Aluno::with('trienio.curso')->select('alunos.*')->get();
```

Which will get me a list of all alunos and their related records (curso and trienio).

Here is the schema of the related tables:

Cursos

```
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| curso | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Trienios

```
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| data_trienio | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| curso_id     | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| oe_id        | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Alunos

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_cartao  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| nome       | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email      | varchar(255)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| trienio_id | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And here are the relevant relationships on the model files:

**Aluno.php**

```
public function trienio()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Trienio');
}
```

**Trienio.php**

```
public function curso()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Curso');
}
```

**Curso.php**

```
public function trienio()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Trienio');
}
```

Like I said in the title, I want to make the query constrained by the collection, what is the best way of doing that?

**P.S - I only want to get the alunos (and their respective relationships) that are constrained according to the collection.**

Comment: Can you give an example of the query you would want? I can see a few different ways you could constrain this query and they would all give different results e.g. do you want to get all the `alunos` and only get the relationships that are relevant or do you only want to get the `alunos` that have those relationships.

Comment: edited. only the relationships that are relevant.

Comment: So you still want to get all the `alunos` rows?

Comment: not all the aluno rows. the aluno rows that match the constraints according to the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$alunos = Aluno::with('trienio.curso');

foreach ($trienios as $trienio) {
    $alunos->orWhereHas('trienio', function ($query) use ($trienio) {
        $query->where('data_trienio', $trienio['trienio'])
            ->whereHas('curso', function ($query) use ($trienio) {
                $query->where('curso', $trienio['curso']);
            });
    });
}

$alunos->get();
```

The above is assuming that there is a `$trienios` is already set with the data from the session.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @BadLaravelProgrammer Glad I could help!